# expected value of expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Consider m.g.f  $ \ \forall n \geq 0: f(n):=\log E(e^{nS_1})$ with  $S_i=z+i-\sum\limits_{j=1}^iY_j$.

$(Y_j)_j$ are i.i.d random variables and $Y_j \in \mathbb{N}_0$

I want to compute: $$\mathbb{E}[e^{cY_{t+1} - f(-c)}]=\mathbb{E}(\frac{e^{cY_{t+1}}}{\mathbb{E}(e^{-cS_1})})= \frac{\mathbb{E}(exp(cY_{t+1}))}{ exp(-c(u+1)) \mathbb{E}(exp(cY_1))}= e^{c(z+1)}$$
Is that right?

Comment: You have to see $\mathbb E[e^{-nS_1}]$ as a constant, as such you can pull it out from the expectation to get $\frac{\mathbb E[e^{cY_{t+1}}]}{\mathbb E[e^{-nS_1}]}$. Also I think there is an error in your expression, there shouldn't be any $n$ there but $-c$ instead.

Comment: @P.Quinton: Yes that was my mistake. It should be $c$. Can I simply further then?

Comment: Yes you can. Try plugging in the formula for $S_1$. You may want to edit your post when you tried if you still didn't manage.

Comment: @P.Quinton: What do you think of my result?

Comment: Looks good to me, except that you have $u$ that should be a $z$ on the denominator.

Comment: Yes thank you very much;)